# Python socket reconnecting

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket program and I want to keep the connection running all the time, if someone disconnects I want to start listening to a new connection and keep the program running.

I used this code:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket()
socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
socket.listen(1)
(con, address) = socket.accept()
while con.recv(1024) != b'exit':
    pass
else:
    con.close()
    socket.listen(1)
    (con, address) = socket.accept()
```

However, after the else clause the program runs further and the while statement will not run again and I do want the while statement to repeat itself. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply make a containing loop...

```
import socket

while True:
    socket = socket.socket()
    socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
    socket.listen(1)
    (con, address) = socket.accept()
    while con.recv(1024) != b'exit':
        pass
    else:
        con.close()
```

Comment: Haha thanks, I broke my head trying to figure it out!